# Returning a Node in an abstract case (Java)

Tags: java, generics, stack

I have the following interface for a stack:

```
public interface Stack <E> {

   public void push (E item);

   public E pop();

   public E peek();

   public String toString();

}
```

and the following class that implements it:

```
public class LinkBasedStack<E> implements Stack<E> {

   Node<E> head;

   public void push (E item){
       if (head == null){
           Node newNode = new Node(item);
           head = newNode;
       }
   }

   public E pop(){
       return head; //error
   }
}
```

The incompleteness of the methods notwithstanding, I face the issue of Java telling me that:

"Type mismatch: can't covert from Node to E".

How can I keep the stack generic but also be able to return the Node?

Comment: Not what you asked - but there's never any need to list `String toString();` in an interface, since all classes inherit that particular method from `Object`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `pop()` method signature declares that you are returning a value of type `E`, but head is declared as a `Node<E>`, which is not the same.  In any case, you probably don't want to return the `Node` itself.  The fact that you are storing `E` in a `Node` is an implementation detail you don't need to expose to the user of your `Stack` class.

I would assume that the implementation of your `Node` class has some sort of method to pull the stored data out.

Try something like:

```
public E pop() {
    // don't forget to point head to the next Node on the stack
    return head.getValue();
}
```

Comment: Can't believe I didn't think of that. My Node had E type value, so I could just return that. Thanks!!